# Lessc - Create Source Maps - Wrong paths

Tags: less, source-maps

stackoverflowI am trying to create a source map with lessc so I am able to debug css in chrome.
I am using the terminal.

Unfortunately does the generated file contain wrong file paths. It seems it does mix up relative paths with absolute paths.

My command:

```js
lessc --source-map=sites/all/themes/bootstrap_base/css/index.css.map 
--source-map-basepath=sites/all/themes/bootstrap_base/css
sites/all/themes/bootstrap_base/less/style.less
sites/all/themes/bootstrap_base/css/style.css
```

As a result my paths look like this:

```
../less//Volumes/DATA/WORK/RESOURCES/WORKSPACE/MAMP_HTDOCS/BASE.drupal/sites/all/themes/bootstrap_base/bootstrap/less/normalize.less
```

What I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Don't use `>` there (`>` means you ask `lessc` to output result to the console which is redirected to the file after `>`, i.e. this simply means the compiler can't know what the output file path is).

Comment: Also notice that all those options you specify *after* `>` don't get to the compiler at all. In other words use standard command line pattern: `lessc options srcfile dstfile`.

Comment: I used now this command:
(Look at modified question)

- still the same issue

Comment: Anybody please? For now I have to fix every time the paths by hand - which adds 5 minutes each time I update the css.